# Android studio - Is it possible to change swipe refresh position?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have embedded sites in my blog and I made an app with Android Studio. My problem is that it refreshes my page every time I scroll down. I don't have this problem if I make a post, only with the embedded sites.

[image: My blog]

[image: Where I want to swipe]

```
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        WebView webView;
        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.loadUrl("https://fddfdf.blogspot.com/?m=0");
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.setInitialScale(1);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
            initializeRefreshListener();

        }

        private class MywebClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }

        }

        private void initializeRefreshListener() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            webView.reload();
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

My question is if I can set my app to refresh only when I swipe from the top side of the blog.

Comment: post your current code, always!! logs also may be helpful

Comment: You are right. I did it